# ParallelEnumerable.Aggregate for several methods

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, plinq

Start to learn multithreading. Have 3 methods to calculate a sum, average, and product of square roots of an array.

At first, I make three separate blocking calls using PLINQ. Then I thought that it would be nice to be able to make it in a single call and return an object with sum, product, and average at the same time. I read that ParallelEnumerable.Aggregate can help me with this, but I totally don't know how to use it.

I would be really grateful for some explanation how to use this function in my case, good/bad aspects of this approach.

```
public static double Average(double[] array, string tool)
        {
            if (array == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));
            double sum = Enumerable.Sum(array);
            double result = sum / array.Length;
            Print(tool, result);
            return result;
        }

        public static double Sum(double[] array, string tool)
        {
            if (array == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));
            double sum = Enumerable.Sum(array);
            Print(tool, sum);
            return sum;
        }

        public static void ProductOfSquareRoots(double[] array, string tool)
        {
            if (array == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));
            double result = 1;
            foreach (var number in array)
            {
                result = result * Math.Sqrt(number);
            }
            Print(tool, result);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three aggregated values (average, sum and product of square roots) that you want to compute can each be computed by performing a single pass over the numbers. Instead of doing this three times (one for each aggregated value) you can do this once and aggregate the three values inside the loop (this should save time).

The average is the sum divided by the count and as you already are computing the sum you only need the count in addition to get the average. If you know the size of the input you don't even have to count the items but here I assume that the size of the input is unknown in advance.

If you want to use LINQ you can use `Aggregate`:

```
var aggregate = numbers.Aggregate(
    // Starting value for the accumulator.
    (Count: 0, Sum: 0D, ProductOfSquareRoots: 1D),
    // Update the accumulator with a specific number.
    (accumulator, number) =>
    {
        accumulator.Count += 1;
        accumulator.Sum += number;
        accumulator.ProductOfSquareRoots *= Math.Sqrt(number);
        return accumulator;
    });
```

The variable `aggregate` is a `ValueTuple<int, double, double>` with the items `Count`, `Sum` and `ProductOfSquareRoots`. Before C# 7 you would use an anonymous type. However, that would require an allocation for each value in the input sequence slowing down the aggregation. By using a mutable value tuple the aggregation should become faster.

`Aggregate` works with PLINQ so if `numbers` is of type `ParallelQuery<T>` and not `IEnumerable<T>` then the aggregation will be performed in parallel. Notice that this requires the aggregation to be both associative (e.g. `(a + b) + c = a + (b + c)` and commutative (e.g. `a + b = b + a`) which in your case is true.

PLINQ has an overhead so it might not perform better compared to single threaded LINQ depending on the number of elements in your sequence and how complex the calculations are. You will have to measure this yourself to determine if PLINQ speeds things up. However, you can use the same `Aggregate` expression in both LINQ and PLINQ making your code easy to switch from single threaded to parallel by inserting `AsParallel()` the right place.

Answer (score 3):

Note: you must initialize the `result` variable with the value 1, because otherwise you will always get 0.

Note 2: instead of `Enumerable.Sum(array)`, just write `array.Sum()`.

<strike>No, the `Aggregate` method won't help you to calculate the three functions at the same time.</strike> See Martin Liversage answer.

---

[KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) ;)

```
if (array == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));

var sum = array.Sum();
var average = array.Average();
var product = array.Aggregate(1.0, (acc, val) => acc * Math.Sqrt(val));
```

Can be simplified:

```
var average = sum / array.Length;
```

This eliminates an extra pass through the array.

---

Want to parallelize?

```
var sum = array.AsParallel().Sum();
//var average = array.AsParallel().Average(); // Extra pass!
var average = sum / array.Length; // More fast! Really!
var product = array.AsParallel().Aggregate(1.0, (acc, val) => acc * Math.Sqrt(val));
```

However, it will probably be slower than the previous method. Such paralleling is justified only for very large collections, in billions of elements.

---

Each pass through the collection takes time. The less passes, the better the performance. From one we have already disposed of, when calculating the average. Let's do just one.

```
double sum = 0;
double product = 1;

foreach (var number in array)
{
    sum += number;
    product = product * Math.Sqrt(number);
}

double average = sum / array.Length;
```

Three results in one pass! We are the best!

---

Let's get back to the subject.

The [Parallel.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx) method allows you to execute several functions in parallel, but it does not get the results from them. It is suitable for calculations of the type "fire and forget".

We can parallelize the computation by running multiple tasks. With help of `Task.WhenAll` waiting for them all completed and get the result.

```
var results = await Task.WhenAll(
        Task.Run(() => array.Sum()),
        Task.Run(() => array.Average()),
        Task.Run(() => array.Aggregate(1.0, (acc, val) => acc * Math.Sqrt(val)))
    );

var sum = results[0];
var average = results[1];
var product = results[2];
```

It is also not effective for a small size collection. But it may be more efficient than the `AsParallel` in some cases.

Another way of writing this approach with tasks. Perhaps it will seem clearer.

```
var sumTask = Task.Run(() => array.Sum());
var avgTask = Task.Run(() => array.Average());
var prodTask = Task.Run(() => array.Aggregate(1.0, (acc, val) => acc * Math.Sqrt(val)));

Task.WaitAll(sumTask, avgTask, prodTask);

sum = sumTask.Result;
average = avgTask.Result;
product = prodTask.Result;
```

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks!